# db2 luw 11.5 sha256 function is not worked

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I ran into the problem of hashing the varchar value using the SHA256 algorithm, for this I use the SYSIBM.HASH function: `select sysibm.hash('17036228142', 2) as value from sysibm.sysdummy1`
but as a result I get the completely wrong value:

> `÷ _6÷Ä ãúnÐ ÄÅ¬¯~v  øB´ÞS Þ ÷ qË`

How do I get the correct result, in the form of:

> `29cdec08b6bb8d21632fdd23c212decc3e25feba7b1fc55d1d706cae023d9274`

Thanks a lot

Comment: It is a completely right value, because HASH() returns a VARBINARY (and not a printable hex string that you want). You must convert the varbinary into a  hex string...do your research.

Comment: `values hash('17036228142', 2);` would be a much shorter example

Answer (score 1):

the Db2-LUW HASH() function returns a varbinary .
This is not a printable string!

If you want to see the hex equivalent, try using the HEX() function on the result of the HASH() function:

Example:

```
values  hex(hash('Charlie at IBM', 2))  may result in:

1BC256DA300813A04E2C82C45243E6692F157F29F30AB74D2A63667505AD6C97
```

Notice that when you use the Db2 CLP (command line processor) it may automatically do the conversion for you. But if you submit the SQL from a program, you must do the conversion.